# The second list is being filled over and over. What is wrong with this python code?

Tags: python, list, append

```
def firstnonrepeatingchar(str1):
    list1=list(str1)
    list2=[]
    print(list1)
    for ch in list1:
        if ch not in list2:
            a=list1.count(ch)
            list2.append(a)
    print(list2)
    for x in list2:
        if(x==1):
            print(list1[x+2])



string1="aaabccc"
firstnonrepeatingchar(string1)
```

The output is giving list2 as
[3,3,3,1,3,3,3]
how to make it only as [3,1,3]?

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this `[3,3,3,1,3,3,3]` because you are appending every time you encounter the character.

A better approach would be to use `OrderedSet` that does not allow duplicates and preserves the order.

```
from orderedset import OrderedSet

def firstnonrepeatingchar(str1):
    s = OrderedSet(str1)
    list2 = []
    for ch in s:
        list2.append(str1.count(ch))
    # or list2 = [str1.count(c) for c in s]
    print(list2)

string1="aaabccc"
firstnonrepeatingchar(string1)
```

---

Errors in your code:

```
if ch not in list2:
```

`ch` will never be there in `list2` because you never append `ch` to `list2`, you append the count.

Fix for your code:

```
def firstnonrepeatingchar(str1):
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for ch in str1:
        if ch not in list1:
            list1.append(ch)
            list2.append(str1.count(ch))
    print(list2)
```

Although, I do not recommend this `if ch not in list1:`. It performs a linear search. Using a `set` will be better for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the if statement in the first loop, `if ch not in list2:`, you're checking if the current **character** is in list2. But you're appending the **counts** to that list. So it never passes that check and adds the count for every character in the string/array. I would suggest using a dictionary to store characters and their counts together, so then the if statement can check if the key (character) exists, and if not can add the key with its count. Then you should be able to find the first non-repeating character (the first entry in the dic with a 1 count). As of Python 3.6 dictionaries will remember the order of insertion, otherwise use an OrderedDict.